# Efficient vector selection in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Is there an efficient numpy mechanism to generate an array of values from a 2D array given a list of indexes into that array?

Specifically, I have a list of 2D coordinates that represent interesting values in a 2D `numpy` array.  I calculate those coordinates as follows:

```
nonzeroValidIndices = numpy.where((array2d != noDataValue) & (array2d != 0))
nonzeroValidCoordinates = zip(nonzeroValidIndices[0],nonzeroValidIndices[1])
```

From there, I'm building a map by looping over the coordinates and indexing into the numpy array one at a time similarly to this simplified example:

```
for coord in nonzeroValidCoordinates:       
    map[coord] = array2d[coord]
```

I have several massive datasets I'm iterating this algorithm over so I'm interested in an efficient solution.  Through profiling, I suspect that `array2d[coord]` line is causing some pain.  Is there a better vector form to generate an entire vector of values from `array2d` or am I stuck with indexing one at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try something like:

```
array2d[ix_(nonzeroValidIndices[0],nonzeroValidIndices[1])]
```

Or if you really want to use `nonzeroValidCoordinates`:

```
unzip = lambda l: [list(li) for li in zip(*l)]
array2d[ix_(unzip(nonzeroValidCoordinates))]
```

*Source:* [Link](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#head-13d7391dd7e2c57d293809cff080260b46d8e664)

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
a = np.arange(100).reshape((10,10))
ii = np.where(a > 27) # your nonzeroValidIndices
b = np.zeros_like(a) # your map
b[ii] = a[ii]
```

You can use the result of `np.where` to index an array as I show above. This should accomplish something similar to what you're doing without looping, but I'm not entirely clear what your target 2D array is actually suppose to be from your question. Not knowing what `map` is, it seems just like you're copying data over into the same sized array.

Comment: I understood the word `map` as dictionary. Is that what you meant @Rich?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course, you can get the values as

```
nonZeroData = array2d[nonzeroValidIndices]
```

if map is a new dict, you could do

```
map = dict(zip(nonzeroValidCoordinates,nonZeroData))
```

If it is an existing dict,

```
map.update(zip(nonzeroValidCoordinates,nonZeroData))
```

If it is an array, then

```
map[nonzeroValidIndices] = nonZeroData
```